# Switching a circuit from a 2 wire dc motor to 3 wire motor

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I am an extreme newbie (having done software all my life, hardware is making me feel super dumb), and big picture is I am trying to replicate this work:

http://words.iame.li/post/112091812552/buttonpusher

Although he seems to be taking some shortcuts which I don't quite understand (where does the yellow and green wire go on the pi? How does he join the green wire up to the power supply?)

As part of my learning, I decided to do it by steps on an established kit. I have just completed this circuit: [image: https://www.sunfounder.com/forum/superkit-v2---lesson-7--dc-motor?p=2]

As you can see from that rather complicated chart (which i assume is for protecting the RaspPi) the motor is ultimately powered by two wires, positive and negative.

I now want to take this setup, WHICH WORKS!, and apply it to the Futaba servo which he uses ([https://www.amazon.com/Futaba-FUTM0031-S3003-Standard-Servo/dp/B0015H2V72](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015H2V72)) but simply plugging in my wires to the red and black receptors of the Futaba servo didnt work, presumably because I need a neutral wire to ground the new white wire from the Futaba? I must be sounding so retarded now to you guys, but I appreciate any and all tips as to fundamental concepts i must go and learn and terms and things i need to google. Please help!

Comment: Kudos for a well written question, with links so we can see what you're trying to do!

Comment: for future readers - the kit i am using is sunfounder super kit v2.0 for raspberry pi and that chart was from project 7: https://www.sunfounder.com/forum/superkit-v2---lesson-7--dc-motor?p=2

Answer (score 3):

The standard motor they use, and a standard Futaba servo, work in different ways.

A standard permanent magnet DC motor just turns continuously when you apply power to it, speed more or less proportional to voltage, or in the case of PWM, to duty cycle. It's just dumb physics-obeying hardware. The L293 is a power switch, a full H-bridge, which takes the low power logic levels from the Pi, and switches higher currents capable of turning the motor. It can drive +/-, or -/+ to the motor to make it turn in either direction, those wires to the motor are not power supplies or always +ve or -ve. U2 and 3 are opto isolators, for bomb-proof isolation between the Pi and the motor and its power supplies, but not absolutely necessary for function.

A standard servo contains a motor in it somewhere, but has a very different function. It is intended to go to a specific shaft angle within an angular range of about half a turn. It is used for controlling rudder and throttle position on radio controlled models. It contains a gearbox, position sensor, and some comparator and drive electronics. The desired angle of the shaft is encoded in the length of logic pulses sent into the white wire. A 1.5mS pulse is central, 1mS full left, 2mS full right. Typically, pulses are delivered every 20mS or so. In the absence of a pulse, it will hold the last position.

If you want to drive it directly from your Pi, connect red and black supply wires to +5 and gnd respectively. Connect the white wire directly to the one of the GPIOs, or to the output of either U2 or U3 if you want the opto-isolation for safety, or via the 1k resistor (some protection) that your first project uses.  Use your software skills to generate a stream of pulses on the GPIO, length 1mS to 2mS, 20mS apart.

I've not looked myself, but I would not be surprised at all if you googled 'pi servo open source', and found stuff ready to run that would put the right sort of pulses onto the GPIO.

The author of the first project was misleading slightly when he said 'the servo spins for a few seconds', because it doesn't, it just changes position (noisily, over a second or so) to push the button.

If you connected red and black from your servo to the output of the 293, I hope it didn't go bang when you applied reverse voltage to it. I would hope that as servos are designed to be supplied by batteries (which can be reversed) and used by youngsters, they would be designed to survive supply reversal.

In software terms, what you're trying to do is plug a USB lead into a 3.5mm audio jack! Both have their standards and levels of complexity, but you're lacking the experience at the moment to anticipate how different.

If you have got your existing L293 drive working, then this is the way to modify it to use your new servo, with full bomb-proof opto-isolation of any spikes from the motor to the Pi.

[image]

A number of things to note. The 5v servo supply is totally isolated from the Pi's. All the GND symbols are for this 5v supply. There is no ground connection between the Pi's supply and the servo's 5v supply. I've taken the servo 5v supply to the output of the optos. The +3.3v supply to the input of the optos is still the Pi +3.3v supply.

I've replaced the functionality of the L293 with that of the servo, note that it only needs one logic input, where the L293 used 3. I've coloured the 3 servo connections appropriately.

Comment: hi Neil, thanks for the very lucid explanations! in particular I enjoyed the explanation of difference between DC and standard servo. followup question - you mentioned driving it directly from my Pi. does that mean I don't have to include the external power source? I think that is what some sources I read have been telling me NOT to do (since it can deplete the PI's power), and indeed the author of the first project did include one. I think adding protection is what I am having the most difficulty with and thats what i was trying to get from the kit only to find out its inapplicable :(

Comment: i also found out that RPI's GPIO only provides from 2 mA up to 16 mA. I have no idea how much the Futaba servo needs but it looks like it will be >250mA just based on servos in general. so basically it seems very ill advised to drive directly from my Pi? if so I really have to figure out how to connect the external power source, either using the L293 switch, or using the iameli's (the author of first project) method of duct taping power directly into the system?

Comment: You connect the red/black servo supply to a +5v power supply. The white control wire is a logic input, directly compatible with a Pi GPIO. You must not confuse power supplies (fixed voltage, plenty of current), with logic signals (mA to sub-mA), and the poetntial power output of a Pi board on the supply pins (severely limited by the size of the regulator that happens to be on the board). I suggest you get a dedicated wall plug-in USB power supply, these are capable of supplying 500mA+, to power your servo red/black.

Comment: Then connect the black of that supply to the black/ground on your Pi, to establish a common ground. Then connect the white control input to your GPIO. The GPIO is perfectly capable to supply the fraction of 1mA demanded by the white wire control input of the servo. However, if you power it from the output of U2, the opto-isolator will give bomb-proof protection to your Pi, should any spikes come back from the motor. The 1k resistor shown by the button pusher link provides some protection to the Pi by limiting any spike current. Personally, I would just connect the white directly to the GPIO!

Comment: Considering the 'WHICH WORKS' setup, what do you use to provide 5v power to that?

Comment: Take what iameli has done with his button pusher diagram, and replicate that, except subsituting a 5v power supply for his 12v 2A supply. Maybe he used a 12v capable servo? The designers of the Pi **expect** people to connect things to the GPIO pins, so they are already protected to some extent. They can be shorted to either rail, and touched with a finger without keeling over and dying. If you want to add  more porection, then instead of connecting the white wire directly to a gpio, connect a U2 to the gpio, and connect the white to that. I'll draw a diagram later today when I have time.

Comment: The most helpful thing before I draw a diagram is to say that the L293+motor is more or less equivalent to the servo, as far as connections to the Pi and power supply are conecnerned. The L293's 1A and 2A inputs ar elogic inputs, electrically equivalent to the servo white wire, the VCC and gnd connection equivalent to the red and black servo wires. Remove the L293 anjd motor, and replace them with the servo, white wire to U2 output, red and black wires to the 5v and gnd that were powering the L293.

Comment: Modified your L293 diagram to replace motor with servo, with separate power supply and full isolation.